# Encoding UTF8 char to byte table or formula

Tags: c#, utf-8

Hello i want to hard code the values of some utf 8 characters to bytes.

E.g: `'$'`,`'-'`,`'+'`;

For `'$'` how is the byte value calculated from this :

```
     symbol      char              octal code point      binary code point  binary utf8
        $         U+0024              044                 010 0100       00100100
```

What is the value from this columns that gets encoded to byte?

```
public class Constants{
   public const byte dollar= [value pick from where ?]   
   public const byte minus= [pick value from where?]
}
```

Which column from above should i look for to encode a byte?
Is there any formula between the `char` column value  and the byte value?

Comment: I want to  have them in a lookup.I am doing a lot of processing and i need them hard-coded.

Comment: If you mean the column is `char` then the value should be `'\u0024'`. U+0024 is the notation for a Unicode codepoint, whereas `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. And for "binary code point", you'd need 21 bits. For "binary utf8", you'd need one to four groups of 8 bits.

Comment: Tables are accessible through code, for example `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`. But if you really want tables, there are scads at Unicode.org. Maybe start with a human-friendly one [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). BTW—some answers mention another character set called ASCII, presumably on the theory that it would help when learning Unicode to relate it to something that you know; But there is no particular reason that you should know ASCII since you probably don't use (it even if you think you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASCII chars (so chars in the range 0-127), you can simply cast them

```
public const byte dollar = (byte)'?';
```

Otherwise:

```
public const byte dollar = 0x0024;
```

So the `char` column. Remove the `U+` and add a 0x. Valid only for characters in the range 0x0000-0x007F.

Note that there is no difference in the compiled code: [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvK2h5gewDtYIvGFHaUC4zgGM+sAsACe8AgBNuGDBAQEAvAQAUC+AEoA5ABITFMRLrT+MOYrgq1GhI114AHnjz0ALFYAvkFAA=):

```
public const byte dollar = (byte)'$';
public const byte dollar2 = 0x0024;
```

gets compiled to:

```
.field public static literal uint8 dollar = uint8(36)
.field public static literal uint8 dollar2 = uint8(36)
```

With C# 7.0, if you hate the world and you want to obfuscate your code, you can:

```
public const byte dollar = 0b00100100;
```

(they added binary literals, `0b` is the prefix)

Comment: And is there any table to look them up?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian You can write `(byte)'x'` and it is equivalent and mor readable... What table do you need? Or you mean for multi-byte utf8?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian I normally use https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm when I want some informations about a unicode character.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the same code would get generated using your notation `byte(symbol)`.I do not think i need a table anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The characters you refer to are not UTF-8 characters. So they are single-byte characters. (Note that UTF-8 only uses 2 bytes for characters outside the ASCII character set)

Since the above, you can just cast them:

```
public const byte dollar = (byte)'$';
```

If you would need a UTF-8 character in bytes, you should use:

```
public static readonly byte[] trademark = new byte[] { 194, 153 };
```

Or, more explicit, but also worst for performance:

```
public static readonly byte[] trademark = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\u0099");
```